# Web Scraping to get the link the returns the file based on a selection in a list of a JavaScript page

Tags: javascript, url, web-scraping, download

To make it extremely didactic, there is a website called D, with pages for different indicators, where each page has a list of files for this indicator.

So, I need to create a routine to download a unique file (`Exportar todas as selecionadas` is the download button) based on a previously selected options of files (the files are selected based on the check button on the column `Valores`)  of this [link](http://www6.sistemaindustria.org.br/gpc/externo/listaResultados.faces?cp=). It is the page of the indicator W.

So, I was trying to find a way to get the link of the retrieved file of the selection of the files I want from indicator W, but the [url that I could get](http://www6.sistemaindustria.org.br/gpc/externo/listaResultados.faces) when copying the supposed link used to download the file using chrome, firefox or safari, returns to the page of the indicator W where the files selected are the ones I had previously made on the same browser.